# Advancing a list iterator

Tags: c++, list, loops

Is there any way of starting the index of the second for loop to (i+1)? I tried mucking with advance but if I insert it in the for loop it will advance by 1 for every iteration. I just want it to start at (i+1) and carry on.

```
for (list< list<string> >::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
    if (i -> front() == s)
        for(list<string>::const_iterator j = i ->begin(); j != i -> end(); j++)
            cout << *j << "  ";
```

- `j = i -> begin() + 1` threw an error.
- `j = advance(i, 1) -> begin()` failed as well.

Comment: list<string>::const_iterator j = i ->begin() **+ 1**. But then you better be sure that `i` has at least one element.

Comment: Hey Jon, my list is definitely not empty, and I tried your method but it kept throwing an error.

Comment: Ah yes, that would not work in the general case. `std::next` is correct, although that requires C++11. `++(i->begin())` for C++03.

Comment: `std::advance` only needs to be used correctly. The error with `it + 1` happens because list iterators are not random-access iterators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) which does not modify its argument

```
std::list<std::string>::const_iterator j = std::next(i->begin());
```

or deduce the iterator type with `auto`

```
auto j = std::next(i->begin());
```

Use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) when you want to advance a given iterator by some distance.  `advance(it, n)` achieves `it += n`, while `next(it, n)` achieves `it + n`.  Advance doesn't return anything, it does its work on its input.

`operator+` with an integral won't work for `std::list` because it has a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), the binary plus is only supported by [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).

These utilities provided by [`<iterator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator) use some template magic to figure out the best way to advance an iterator. In short, if you give `next` something that doesn't have an `operator+`, it will make a copy and repeatedly call `++` N times.